Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowVersion
Upgrade from 9.1.1 to 10.3.1
Full error:
Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowVersion. No matching constructor was found. Constructor parameters:

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Sitecore.Exceptions.ConfigurationException: Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowVersion. No matching constructor was found. Constructor parameters:

This is only referenced to the Sitecore.config. Any clue on what/where to look for?
Any help? Thanks

I have updated the answer below. Hope that helps you to solve this issue.

Can you check if the processor Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowVersion, Sitecore.Kernel inside the initialize pipeline looks like below inside the sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx page.

It should contain resolve as true with the parameters as above.
Update
In Sitecore 9.1, resolve as true parameter is missing inside the Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowVersion processor.

Therefore in order to resolve this issue in Sitecore 10.3.1, you can add patch as below.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
     <pipelines>
        <initialize>
            <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowVersion, Sitecore.Kernel" set:resolve="true">
            </processor>
        </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

There is. However, when I add the prefix it set:resolve, it throws an error that the the prefix set is not defined. I just put resolve instead, and it fixes the issue. Please let me know if this is also correct. :)

@bonhaku Did you added the xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" inside the configuration file as defined above.

Got it. Adding that still works. Thank you!

If you extract the DLL of Sitecore.Kernel for the Sitecore 10.3.1 version and find for the class ShowVersion you will see that this constructor is deprecated. Here are the details.
/// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowVersion" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="log">The log to output information.</param>
    /// <param name="domainManager">The domain manager.</param>
    /// <param name="factory">The factory to construct well-known processors.</param>
    /// <param name="instanceName">Name of the current instance in scaled setup.</param>
    /// <param name="debugEnabled">If set to <c>true</c> ASP.NET debugging is enabled.</param>
    /// <param name="logProcessInfoInterval">The interval to check the necessity of logging process information.</param>
    [Obsolete("This member is deprecated. Please use ShowVersion(BaseLog, BaseDomainManager, BaseFactory, IConfigurationRulesContext, string, bool, TimeSpan) instead.")]
    protected ShowVersion(
      BaseLog log,
      BaseDomainManager domainManager,
      BaseFactory factory,
      string instanceName,
      bool debugEnabled,
      TimeSpan logProcessInfoInterval)
      : this(log, domainManager, factory, ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfigurationRulesContext>(), instanceName, debugEnabled, logProcessInfoInterval)
    {
    }


You need to use this.
ShowVersion(BaseLog, BaseDomainManager, BaseFactory, IConfigurationRulesContext, string, bool, TimeSpan) 

Hope this helps.
